# Rails: How to create through a long :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

I want to create a result_unit like this `Member.first.workouts.first.workout_sets.first.result_unit.create({"name"=>"test"})` but I also want to have the possibility to use `Member.first.result_unit.create({"name"=>"test"})`.

This is my Setup:

```
Member.rb

has_many :workouts
has_many :workout_sets, through: :workouts
has_many :result_units, through: :workout_sets

Workout.rb

belongs_to :member
has_many :workout_sets

WorkoutSet.rb

belongs_to :workout
has_one :result_unit
accepts_nested_attributes_for :result_unit

ResultUnit.rb

belongs_to :member
belongs_to :workout_set
```

Create in WorkoutSet-Controller

```
def create
        @workout = current_user.workouts.find(params[:workout_id])
        @workout_set = @workout.workout_sets.create(workout_set_params)
        @result_unit = @workout.find(@workout_set).result_unit.create(result_unit_params)
        redirect_to workout_path(@workout)
    end
```

I get the error `undefined method create for nil:NilClass` for the create of the ResultUnit.

Comment: That's because @workout_set's result_unit is `nil`. What about `@workout.find(@workout_set).result_unit = ResultUnit.create(result_unit_params)`?

Comment: `@workout.find()` shouldn't work. find is a class method, not an instance method.

Comment: Yeah. It returns `NoMethodError in WorkoutSetsController#create
undefined method find for #<Workout:0x00000005c468f0>`

Comment: @LannyBose is right. It'd be better to assign the result_unit to the workset. `@workset.result_unit = ResultUnit.create(result_unit_params)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach here is assigning the `ResultUnit` to the `WorkoutSet`. Since that `WorkoutSet` is associated with the workout, it'll have the result_unit.

```
@result_unit = @workout_set.result_unit = ResultUnit.create(result_unit_params)
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've defined @workout_set, you don't need to re-find it again. It's already in memory.

```
@result_unit = @workout_set.create_result_unit(result_unit_params)
```

Note the change in syntax. Take a look at [the Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for associations. For one-to-one relationships (`belongs_to` and `has_one`) the method is `create_other()` instead of `others.create()`.